# Malloc function doesn´t work properly

Tags: c

I'm getting a problem whit `malloc()`, don't know what's happening. I'm compiling with MinGW.

Cadena is just a `typedef` for `char *`, and `leer_dato()` is a function that returns a string.

```
Cadena leer_con_formato(const char * formato)
{
    int i = 0;
    Cadena dato = leer_dato();
    if (strlen(dato) != strlen(formato))
        return NULL;
    char * nuevo_dato = (char *)malloc(strlen(dato)); // Here's the problem
    if (!nuevo_dato)
        return NULL;
    while (dato[i] != '\0')
    {
        switch (formato[i])
    {
        case '0':
            if (!isdigit(dato[i]))
                return NULL;
            nuevo_dato[i] = dato[i];
            i++;
            break;
        case 'C':
            if (!isalpha(dato[i]))
                return NULL;
            nuevo_dato[i] = dato[i];
            i++;
            break;
        case 33 ... 47:
        case 58 ... 64:
        case 91 ... 96:
        case 123 ... 126:
            if (!ispunct(dato[i]))
                return NULL;
            nuevo_dato[i] = dato[i];
            i++;
            break;
        default:
            return NULL;
    }
}
nuevo_dato[i] = NULO;
return nuevo_dato;
}
```

Comment: "I'm getting a problem". What exactly is the "problem"? Don't you think it would make sense to tell us what you are observing? And please provide a [mcve]. We can't debug incomplete code (e.g what does `leer_dato` do?).

Comment: so what is the problem? What do you expect and what does actually happen?

Comment: `malloc(strlen(dato));` --> `malloc(strlen(dato) + 1);`

Comment: you should always check the return value of functions so that they are what you expect them to be

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allocating enough memory. If `strlen` returns for example **5**, then that means that your string contains 5 chars **+ 1** for the terminating 0-byte. So when allocating memory for a string you'll have to do it like so:

```
char * nuevo_dato = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(dato) + 1));
```

The `sizeof(char)` is optional.

Comment: Note: Cast `(char*)` not needed either.